# Invalid Retention Stage Defined on Documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, retention

I am trying to set up a Retention Policy on a Site Collection level for SharePoint 2013. I've created a couple of 2010 Reusable Workflows on the Document Content Type. I then went to the top site->Site Settings->Site Content Types.

From there, I went to the **Document** content type settings. In the settings, I went to **Workflow Settings** and added my workflows to the content type.

After adding the workflows to the **Document** content type, I went to **Information Management Policy Settings** and enabled Retention. I specified the retention events to start a workflow. I now have the following retention events:

```
Event                       Action                                Recurrence
Date Created + 30 days      Start the Retention Email workflow
Date Modified + 1 years     Start the Retention-1 Policy workflow
Date Modified + 2 years     Start the Retention-2 Policy workflow
Date Modified + 3 years     Start the Retention-3 Policy workflow
```

The problem I get is when I go to the individual documents and check their compliance details. The details specifies that the action for each of the stages above is: **Invalid retention stage defined**.

Any ideas why the content type seems to have a valid retention stage, but each individual document does not?

FYI, my information management policy and Expiration policy timer jobs execute daily. Also, I don't know if it matters or not, but I don't have a content publishing hub. If I make the changes for Information Management Policy on the Document content type, would I need to "Publish" the changes? If so, how would I go about doing so?

EDIT: I just went to the library settings for a document library, and then to Workflow Settings. There is a drop-down for **Show workflow associations of this type**. When I select the **Document** option, there are no workflows listed! There should be workflows listed whenever I associate a workflow with a content type!

The culprit seems to be that the workflows are not being associated with the document libraries. However, when I add the workflows to the Document Content Type, I make sure that the **Add this workflow to all related content types** is selected.

One last thing, there are document libraries that work. If that document library is on the top level site then it works. However, any library that is part of a sub-site does not!

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be that the workflows were created as Reusable Workflows. The solution was to make them Globally Reusable Workflows.

[image]